# I can get values from one column, but not the next

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So if this gets the values from column C:

```js
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      if(valueToFind==data[i][0]) {
        foundValues.push(data[i][1]);
      }
    }
```

How can I get the values of column D?

Should this not do it?

```js
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      if(valueToFind==data[i][0]) {
        foundValues2.push(data[i][2]);
      }
    }
```

I keep getting `undefined`

edit: full script

```js
function projectTasksAdjDV(e) {

  var activess = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('projectTasksAdj');  
  var colBss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('projectTasks');
  var colCss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('projectTasks');

  var foundValues = [];  
  var foundValues2 = [];  
  var activeCell = activess.getActiveCell();    
  const valueToFind = activeCell.getValue();
  Logger.log("valueToFind = " + activeCell.getValue());

  //  Populate column B data validations
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 1 && activeCell.getRow() > 1){
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearDataValidations();

    //    const valueToFind = activeCell.getValue();
    var data=colBss.getRange(3,1,colBss.getLastRow(),2).getValues();

    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      if(valueToFind==data[i][0]) {
        foundValues.push(data[i][1]);
      }
    }

    if(activeCell.getColumn() != 0){
      var colBValidationRange = foundValues;
      var colBValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colBValidationRange).build();
      activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(colBValidationRule);
    }      
  }

  //  Populate column C & D data validations
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 2 && activeCell.getRow() > 1){

    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearDataValidations();
    activeCell.offset(0, 2).clearDataValidations();

    var data=colCss.getRange(3,2,colCss.getLastRow(),2).getValues();

    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      if(valueToFind==data[i][0]) {
        foundValues.push(data[i][1]);
      }
    }
    Logger.log("foundValues = " + foundValues.join(", "));

    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      if(valueToFind==data[i][0]) {
        foundValues2.push(data[i][2]);
      }
    }
    Logger.log("foundValues2 = " + foundValues2.join(", "));

    if(activeCell.getColumn() != 0){
      var colCValidationRange = foundValues;
      var colCValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colCValidationRange).build();
      activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(colCValidationRule);

      var colDValidationRange = foundValues2;
      var colDValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colDValidationRange).build();
      activeCell.offset(0, 2).setDataValidation(colDValidationRule);
    }      
  }
}
```

Comment: We need to see more of the function.  Like where data was defined.

Comment: @Cooper added the full script

Comment: Checkout my answer below.

Comment: EXCELLENT!  I understand now.  I was limiting information to the rest of the script.  Thank you very much for the explanation! Works perfectly!

Comment: Good.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you change this: `var data=colBss.getRange(3,1,colBss.getLastRow(),2).getValues();`
to this: `var data=colBss.getRange(3,1,colBss.getLastRow(),3).getValues();`

The what you are doing will work.  The range is populated with 4 parameters.

1. starting row
2. starting column
3. Number of rows
4. Number of columns

I just changed the number of columns from 2 to 3.

Comment: Sorry for continuing to change the answer but that's just the way I think.

Comment: @Trey: Also, if you want to get all rows from number 3 to the last one: It should be getRange(3,1,(colBss.getLastRow()-2),3).getValues(); given that the third parameter specifies the NUMBER of rows and not the end row.